# can not delete website: access is denied

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, iis

On my local machine, I am trying to delete a web site as follows and fail in both approaches. Rebooting local machine does not help.

1. Delete Web site via Computer Management Console in IIS.
2. Delete web site folder under c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite

I get the following error dialog:

> Cannot delete mysite: Access is denied.
>
> Make sure the disk is not full or write-protected and that the file is
>   not currently in use.

Answer (score 2):

Stop the IIS service, close any web browsers and try deleting. Else use [Unlocker](http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html) to unlock the files and delete it.

Comment: It might be nicer to IIS to delete the web site in IIS Manager first.